# Not allow element to break bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have something like this

```
   <div class="col-md-12">
            <span class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet SIDE 1</span>
            <span class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet SIDE 2</span>
            <span class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet SIDE 3</span>
            <span class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet SIDE 4</span>
   </div>
```

All is nice on bigger screens, only i have problem in smaller screens, the word collapse in half in second row, please take a look at this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/2441/

When on bigger screens all is well allign, on smaller screens span text size sometimet in half and not so nice. I dont know how big span will it be, it has to have auto, only the nice order has to be, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the .name elements as inline-block elements, to prevent them from wrapping.

```
.name {
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color:red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/2443/).

Answer (score 1):

---

## Preventing mid-word wrapping

---

Please see this [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/DTcHh/2442/)

which uses the

```
text-wrap:none;
```

declaration. It means that words won't be split down the middle, but instead the whole word will wrap to the next line, improving readability and maintaining visual appearance.

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 .name {
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  text-wrap: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <span class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet SIDE 1</span>
  <span class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet SIDE 2</span>
  <span class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet SIDE 3</span>
  <span class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet SIDE 4</span>
</div>
```

---

## Full Block wrapping

---

Please see this [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/DTcHh/2444/)

To stop whole blocks from wrapping, I would add a

```
display: inline-block
```

declaration. It means that the **entire span** will wrap (rather than by word) on resizing of the screen.

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 .name {
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <span class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet SIDE 1</span>
  <span class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet SIDE 2</span>
  <span class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet SIDE 3</span>
  <span class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet SIDE 4</span>
</div>
```